# SQL - Return all records for an account based on comparison between records for that account

Tags: sql, subquery, having

SQL novice here. So, i would like to return records from a table for an account where at least one of those records meets a certain criteria.

We've got a program that should allocate cash to old invoices before new ones. It isn't and i need to find records that have been affected.

I want to return all records for an account if there is; 

 an open amount > 0 for a record that is older than a record for the same account where the Open Amount is zero or less than the gross amount.

 

 

So in the below example, Account A1 has allocated correctly. I want my query to return all the records for accounts B2 and C3.

I think i need to use some combination of HAVING and possibly a subquery but its got me confused! Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you.

```
UKID     ACCOUNT    DATE        OPEN_AMOUNT    GROSS_AMOUNT
1        A1         12/03/14    100            100  
2        A1         12/02/14    0              150
3        B2         21/03/14    0              100  
4        B2         21/02/14    100            100
5        C3         01/03/14    50             100
6        C3         01/02/14    50             100
```

Comment: The way Stack Overflow works is, to show that your question has been answered, you should select the most useful answer and mark it as accepted (check mark at top left of the answer). You don't edit the title to say "Solved". It's not clear which of the answers is actually solving your problem - or if you've solved it in a separate way, please add the information about how you solved it *as an answer* (You're allowed to answer your own questions). That way, it's more useful for other people in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
select *
from   mytable
where  account in (select ext.account
                   from   mytable ext
                   inner join (SELECT account, date 
                              FROM mytable ext 
                              WHERE OPEN_AMOUNT = 0 
                                 or OPEN_AMOUNT < gross_amount) sub
                              on ext.account = sub.account 
                             and ext.date < sub.date
                   where  open_amount > 0)
```

should do.

If you need something more like a chain control it'll be more difficoult.

Can you please specify the database you are using? Some db specific feature can actually help a lot.

Comment: sorry about the slow reply i was in meetings all day yesterday - this appears to have broken the back of the problem! Thanks very much. i would provide an upvote but my account is too young! - to answer your question the db is an IBM AS400 but i have to use an iSeries Data Transfer application on my local machine to query the db. I am a Business Analyst by trade rather than a DBA so i don't have access to the back end really! Thanks for your help though...

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YourTable
WHERE ACCOUNT IN (
                    SELECT DISTINCT ACCOUNT
                    FROM YourTable
                    WHERE OPEN_AMOUNT <> 0
                 )
```

You need that second query to determine all accounts that have a non zero open amount. Then with that list you can get all of the records associated with it.

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't your query return account A1 in my example? I'm trying to avoid selecting those records. I was hoping to only return records where there was an open amount for an earlier record and a later record existed which had either an open amount of 0 or an amount less than the gross amount...